# What purpose does enum constructor have if values are final

Tags: java, enums

Lets take this enum for example

```
public enum Element {
    H("Hydrogen"),
    HE("Helium"),
    // ...
    NE("Neon");
 
    public final String label;
 
    private Element(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

what is this constructor really for and why do we need getter's and setter's if we already set enum values

Comment: "what is this constructor really for" it's for assigning a value to `label`. How else would that happen? And you don't need setters, since enums should be immutable.

Comment: but what does label really do thats what confuses me

Comment: what is labels purpose

Comment: `label` does nothing in and of itself. If that's your entire enum, it is redundant. But you could, say, return it from a method.

Comment: Think of an enum as a regular class which already has a list of its instances. Your code cannot create another `Element` anywhere, all the instances are defined by the enum constants (such as `H`, `HE` etc). If your want to pass values (such as `"Hydrogen"`) to the creation of such an instance, you need a constructor that takes these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Element constructor is called from the declaration of enums since they have one parameter in them.

Comment: what does label really set

Comment: You can't set the label if you don't have the constructor. An enum doesnt have a parameter in the constructor. The additional constructor gives you that possibility.

Comment: @T0milicaVeršić where did you set that parameter? A line such as `H("Hydrogen")` calls the constructor. The constructor is the responsible for dealing with the String parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Enums are just special classes. Yours is essentially equivalent to:

```
public final class Element extends Enum<Element> {
    public static final Element H = new Element(0, "Hydrogen");
    public static final Element HE = new Element(1, "Helium");

    // ... etc

    private final String label;

    private Element(int ordinal, String label) {
      super(...);
      this.label = label;
    }
}
```

(Try decompiling the `.class` file, this is what it will look like)

So, just as with a regular class, if you want to set a field in the class based on some parameter passed when you create the instance, you need to declare a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this question using the code snipped you provided.
So an enum is a data type that can be used to represent a set of fixed constants. and for these constants you will have certain "labels" as additional information for the enum constant.

Therefore, in order to initialize the "label" that you have assigned to each constant, the private constructor of the Enum class is called and the label that you assigned is attached to each enum constant.

```
public enum Element {
        H("Hydrogen"), //string label assigned for enum constant
        HE("Helium"),
        // ...
        NE("Neon");
     
        public final String label; //string variable to handle the label for each constant
     
        private Element(String label) {
            this.label = label; //parameterized constructor to assign the label to each constant
        }
    }
```